# How stable is the block time after Ethereum PoS?

Tags: block-interval, the-merge

I understand that PoW basically depends on luck. If the target block time is 10 minutes, if  lucky, 3 minutes, if unlucky, will not be able to find the hash even after 30 minutes.

How stable is the block time after Ethereum -The Merge?